# in webos 3.0.2 where is the documentation for each "capability"?

Tags: webos, touchpad

I am interested in ultimately creating a connector for a cloud storage service similar to the dropbox account connector, so I am working towards understanding the whole "capability" structure, particularly the DOCUMENT capability type.

I see the example for creating a Contact synergy connector;
https://developer.palm.com/content/api/dev-guide/synergy/creating-synergy-contacts-package.html

(i edited this question, to reflect my progress with the problem. originally, I was looking for the list of names of capabilities, provided by each service. this is achievable over ssh or novacom with the following command;
luna-send -n 1 -f palm://com.palm.service.accounts/listAccounts '{}'
)

p.s. my touchpad only arrived yesterday, so I am a complete newbie on the SDK and platform. though i have installed the SDK and am in developer mode.
pp.s. At the moment I am going in circles with the documentation.